# Silverlight multiple views

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, controls, radio-button

Sorry for dummy question, I'm quite new in Silverlight.

I want to dynamically change the layout in my app: for example, I've got two radio buttons: male and female, and I want to show additional controls depending on the gender selected.

For example; If user checks male option, combobox1 should be shown, and if user checks another radio button, another combobox should be shown **in the same place**.

I can do it with using stackpanel and visible property or with canvas and z property, but I want to know what the best decision is.

And one more question: can one switch through radio buttons, or should use else if statements?

Answer (score 1):

You could do it without code behind.
You could add two states to your control: male and female.
Then you define your two states:

Male state: maleCombobox = Visible, femaleCombobox = Collapsed
Female state: : maleCombobox = Visible, femaleCombobox = Collapsed

Here is the sample xaml (just a quick sample ;) ):

```
<UserControl xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"  x:Class="SilverlightApplication1.MainPage"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

 <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
  <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
   <VisualStateGroup x:Name="MaleFemaleState">
    <VisualState x:Name="FemaleState">
     <Storyboard>
      <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="FemaleCB">
       <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
         <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
       </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
      </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
     </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
    <VisualState x:Name="MaleState">
     <Storyboard>
      <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="MaleCB">
       <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
         <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
       </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
      </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
     </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
   </VisualStateGroup>
  </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

  <i:Interaction.Triggers>
   <ei:PropertyChangedTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=MaleRB}">
    <ei:GoToStateAction StateName="MaleState"/>
   </ei:PropertyChangedTrigger>
   <ei:PropertyChangedTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=FemaleRB}">
    <ei:GoToStateAction StateName="FemaleState"/>
   </ei:PropertyChangedTrigger>
  </i:Interaction.Triggers>

  <StackPanel>
   <RadioButton GroupName="1" x:Name="MaleRB" Content="Male"/>
   <RadioButton GroupName="1" x:Name="FemaleRB" Content="Female"/>

  </StackPanel>

  <Grid Margin="40">
   <ComboBox x:Name="MaleCB" Visibility="Collapsed">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Male"/>
   </ComboBox>
   <ComboBox x:Name="FemaleCB" Visibility="Collapsed">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="female"/>
   </ComboBox>
  </Grid>

 </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Unfortunately for the triggers you need the blend libs. If you don't have blend, you can download a trial or you can define your states and use the VisualStateManager.GoToState in your code behind (http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.visualstatemanager.gotostate(VS.95).aspx). You would listen on the checked event of each radio button and would go to the needed state.

Hope this helps, if you need further explanation just write a comment.

TJ

Answer (score 0):

first of all set GroupName property of the each radio button. Using ChangePropertyAction change visibility of each combobox. e.g.

Visible
            
   
 
            
             Visible